# Preserve list sequence when cluster

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I split a PDF document into paragraphs. I would like to cluster the documents however I need to preserve the order of the paragraphs. Basically, I need to perform sequential clustering.

How can I implement this task?

Thank you.

Comment: Define "cluster". Are you sure it's clustering?

Comment: @Anony Mousse - I would like to concatenate paragraphs of same topic. This must be done in sequential order

Comment: I don't think that is clustering. Check one paragraph at a time, compare it to the previous paragraph...